# Character of $Sym^n V$?

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Is there a formula for the character of $V\otimes_{Sym}W$ in terms of the two characters $X_V$ and $X_W$ ?

I am trying to find the general formula for the character of $Sym^n\ V$ and I don't know how to approach this problem.

We know that $X_{Sym^2\ V} (g)= \frac{1}{2}(X_V(g)^2+ (X_V(g^2))$ , and that

$V\otimes_{Sym}W$ has as eigenvalues the set $\{\lambda_i\mu_j|\ i\leq j\}_{i,j=1}^{n,\ m}$ where $n$ is the smallest of the dimensions of $V$ and $W$ and $m$ is the greatest, and the $\{\lambda_i\}$'s and $\{\mu_j\}$'s are respectively the eigenvalues of the space of the smallest dimension (say $V$) and the greatest (say $W$) , we can write 
$X_V(g).X_W(g)= (\sum \lambda_i)(\sum \mu_j)= \sum_{i\leq j} \lambda_i\mu_j + \sum_{i> j} \lambda_i\mu_j= X_{V\otimes^{Sym} W}\ (g)+ X_{V\otimes^{Alt}\ W}\ (g)- \sum_{i<j} \lambda_i\mu_j$

Comment: The answer here [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84103/characters-of-symmetric-and-antisymmetric-powers)  might be helpful

Comment: Ale0's link is in fact an answer to the question in the title ($Sym^n(V)$). I don't know of anything particularly nice for the one in the body ($V\otimes_{Sym} W$).

Comment: How is $V \otimes_{Sym} W$ defined as a vector space when $V \neq W$?

Comment: @Joppy by quotienting the tensor product by the subspace generated by the elements ($v\otimes w- w\otimes v$)

Comment: Only one of $v \otimes w$ or $w \otimes v$ makes sense inside the tensor product $V \otimes W$ though.

Comment: my mistake! $v\otimes w$ and $w\otimes v$ should be identifiable in the regular tensor product, I wanted it to be the space that has basis $\{v_i\otimes w_j|\ i\leq j\}$ if $\{v_i\},\ \{w_j\}$ are respectively basis for V and W